# как можно использовать turf.js d lealfet?

Tags: typescript, angular

Это нужно для того чтобы обозначить зону перекрытия полигоном другого слоя красным цветом...

пример указан здесь [bboxClip](https://turfjs.org/docs/#bboxClip) (только на bbox)
установил npm install @turf/turf @turf/bbox-clip
делаю import turf.js
[image: import turf]

в html добавил скрипт подключения [turf.js](https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@6.3.0/turf.min.js)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но я не смог использовать метод bboxClip
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как мне можно использовать turf и его методы?

Answer (score 0):

Вы инсталлировали библиотеку, теперь она должна находится в папке `node_modules/@turf/...`, а теперь ее надо правильно подключить к angular-проекту, для этого
найдите файл `angular.json` и в нем поле "scripts", в котором укажите путь к библиотеке:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/@turf/turf/turf.min.js",
  ...
]
```

Когда angular будет собирать ваш проект, он сам все пути пропишет на основе данного файла